# ReactJs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, parsing

I am trying to access the key and values in `payload` in my JSON data, and if the key is present in array, `countTargetOptions`, I will display it in a component.

But I keep getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` when I try to display the data `{payload[0]?.payload?.countTargetOptions[i]}` (note: I added the `?` after reading [React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71151286/react-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-0) but it is still not working).

Before I tried to render the components in a loop, there was no issues. See below my code and a photo of the payload data.

```
const countTargetOptions = [
  "count_targets",
  "count_targets_excluded",
  "count_targets_pending",
  "count_targets_in_progress",
  "count_targets_completed",
  "count_targets_failed",
];

const CustomTooltip = ({ payload}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType> | any) => {

    if( payload && payload.length){
      var targetsData = [];
      let payloadData: any = payload[0].payload;
      for(let i = 0; i < countTargetOptions.length; i++){
        if(payloadData.hasOwnProperty(countTargetOptions[i])){
          let targetOption: string  = countTargetOptions[i].replaceAll('_', ' ');         
          targetsData.push(
          <Typography key = {targetOption} sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} color={"black"} >
          {targetOption} : {payload[0]?.payload?.countTargetOptions[i]}
        </Typography> )

        }
      }
      return (
        <>
        <Card>
          <CardContent>
            {targetsData}

            //Example of what wored before loop
            {/* <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} color={"black"} >
              count targets : {payload[0].payload.count_targets}
            </Typography> */}
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
        </>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: `payload[0]?.payload?.countTargetOptions[i]` there is no such property as `countTargetOptions` in the image you provided.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski to my understanding, the loop goes through the `countTargetOptions` array and indexes each type of count_target, which correspond to the properties in the payload. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Property `countTargetOptions` still doesn't exists and that's why you get an error.

Comment: +1 @KonradLinkowski . Otherwise, your line `if(payloadData.hasOwnProperty` may cause an error when payloadData is undefined. You should add a guard against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted to do this:

```
{targetOption} : {payload[0].payload[countTargetOptions[i]]
```

**About `?.`**

`?.` is an operator that returns `undefined` if the left-hand side is `undefined`. You added it in the wrong places. Doing this:

```
{targetOption} : {payload[0].payload.countTargetOptions?.[i]}
```

would be a little bit better, because you wouldn't get the error then, although the value would still be `undefined`.